# how to highlight entire row from A to F, if the cell in column F contains the text "Pending"

Tags: excel, formatting

this may look easy but I can't seem to figure it out despite searching in here.
I wanted to highlight an entire row from A to F if the text in column F is "Pending".

I already tried using the formula in conditional formatting =SEARCH("Pending", $F1), but it highlighted the next row instead of the one that I need.

Hope you can help me. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4dyVf.png)

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace the formula in the conditional formatting rule with "=$F1="Pending". This should work just fine.

Comment: Glad to help, please consider marking the question as answered (checkmark to the left of the answer).

Answer (score 0):

You coudl follow the below:

Formula: `=$F1="Pending"`

Applies to: `=$A$1:$F$20` you could expand the number of lines by changing number 20

**Results:**

[image]